# EGOTableViewPullRefresh not showing background

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am using this library: [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) I have it all set up like the example and it works. It is when I start customizing the appearance that things go wrong. My code:

```
EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableview.bounds.size.height, self.tableview.frame.size.width, self.tableview.bounds.size.height) arrowImageName:@"pull-refresh-arrow.png" textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] backgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alternate-background"]];
//        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alternate-background"]];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    view.delegate = self;
    [self.tableview addSubview:view];
```

It sets the text and the arrow properly, but not the backgroundColor. I actually tried modifying the table it is attached to from the view having a clear background to see if that would help, but it made no difference.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [MSPullToRefreshController](https://github.com/bogardon/MSPullToRefreshController) because it was easier to customize^^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customizing the background color of **PullRefresh** view you should find the code you want in "**EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m**" file , in line **47**

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:237.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

So you can change the background color easily, I hope that will help you ...